Is it possible to use v-slot in a single file component?
I'm using vue3
ComponentA.vue
<template>
  <slot name="label"></slot>
  <slot></slot>
</template>

Simply using a template will work.
<template>
  <ComponentA>
    <template #label>
      label
    </template >
    <template #default>
      content
    </template >
  </ComponentA>
</template>

Is there any way to extract two templates into a component?
like
<template>
  <ComponentA>
    <ComponentB />
  </ComponentA>
</template>

ComponentA is a component of a library, so I can't modify it.
This is not work.
v-slot must be owned by a custom element.
ComponentB.vue
<template>
  <template #label>
    label
  </template >
  <template #default>
    content
  </template >
</template>


The question lacks clear problem statement. This looks like XY problem, consider explaining your real case in details, so the best solution could be suggested. Generally ComponentB is supposed to contain the template from the "Simply using a template" snippet, <ComponentA><template #label>..., it's unknown why you cannot do that

Maybe it is a XY problem. But actually the structure is<ComponentA><component :is="XXX"></ComponentA>. I can change the component only.

There's no sane way to do it the way you suggested, so the comps need to be refactored somehow. Please, show the exact components and how they are used (both ComponentA and whatever XXX is), this would help to understand your case.
